# Can not add correctly activity indicator

Tags: xamarin

My CreateRegisterView function returns the result I expect

Last lines of my function

```
var content = new StackLayout 
{ 
    Margin = 0, 
    Padding = 0, 
    BackgroundColor = Color.Gold 
};
content.Children.Add(forms);
content.Children.Add(new BoxView 
{ 
    Margin = 0, 
    Color = Color.Red, 
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand 
});

AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(content, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(content, new Rectangle(0f, 0f, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(_ActivityIndicator, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(_ActivityIndicator, new Rectangle(0.5, 0.5, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));

var overlay = new AbsoluteLayout();

overlay.Children.Add(content);
overlay.Children.Add(_ActivityIndicator);

return overlay;
```

[image]

But as soon as I add an activity indicator I have this result
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see any definition of `_ActivityIndicator`. The only explanation for what you're facing would that `_ActivityIndicator`refers to the same instance of `content` in some code You've omitted.

If it's not the case, try changing your bounds getting rid of the `AutoSize` to the `content` view.

Like this:

```
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(content, new Rectangle(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f));
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(content, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(_ActivityIndicator, new Rectangle(0.5, 0.5, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(_ActivityIndicator, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
```

Comment: Thank you for your code proposal. It works but it leaves a line down and to the right :( My forgetfulness: static ActivityIndicator _ActivityIndicator = new ActivityIndicator();

Comment: I followed your advice and I set the margin of content to -1. And everything is ok. Have a nice week :)

Comment: @Mauricio if it works, great. But it was a very weird behavior indeed. The line is because of margins, you did the right thing

Comment: Even though my Xamarin experience is minimal I also think it's strange. I hope this will not be a problem when I validate for Ios. The merit is yours anyway, :)

Comment: On Android devices, you can enable `Show Layout Bounds` at Developer settings. It helps to understand the visual elements behaviors, sometimes.